# Configuring NSAppTransportSecurity in code

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ios9

I have an app that is used by different companies. The user first needs to log in throughout a webservice with always the same base-url. When he is logged in successfully I get a base-url (with htttps) back from the webservice. But this base-url is different for each company.

Now when I start my app in IOS9 and I log in and try to call the webservices with the different base-url, I get this error:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9847, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://81.82.219.213:8080/TechAppService/TechAppService.svc//authuser?login=***&password=***
```

I know that I need to set up the NSAppTransportSecurity dictionary in the info.plist. The problem now is that I don't know how I can set this in code.

Comment: You're question is not, how to enable all arbitrary loads using the info.plist, but how to configure domain specific exceptions at run time, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step-1**

select `info.plist` and click Right --> go to `Source Code`

[image]

**Step-2**

the source code open as `Key` Format , on that key add the following keys in last

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
     <true/>
 </dict>
```

you can see like sample output

[image]

**Step - 3**

it automatically added in your plist just like follows

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its because there are few changes in iOS 9 SDK to use network in apps. you need to add following key in `info.plist` file.

`Step 1`: Open `info.plist` file in your project.

`Step 2`: Add `App Transport Security Settings` key.

`Stpe 3`: Add child key `Allow Arbitrary Loads` and set value to `YES`.

Thats all for more details [read apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please set it in **Info.plist**. For more info see in the given image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
</dict>
```

Paste this into the end of your Info.plist This will allow all connections